# Keeping track as to how long a program ran for in C

Tags: c

How can I keep track of how long my program executed a certain instruction in, for example, if one were to measure the diskusage, that would take time, and at the end my program should give an oupit along the lines of

> real=50.0s user=30.s sys=20.0s

How do I distinguish and gather the system time, and the actual command time?

Comment: This is OS-specific if you want `real/user/sys` breakdowns.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/375913/1410711) might be somewhat relevant/related....

Comment: @nneonneo an example please. I don't understand what you are suggesting

Comment: @RichardMckenna: I'm not suggesting anything. I'm telling you that it is OS-specific, so you should *specify what OS you are targeting*.

Comment: @nneonneo I am using Linux. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`getrusage`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrusage.2.html) in Linux:

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>

...

struct rusage rusage;

getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &rusage);
/* use rusage.ru_utime and rusage.ru_stime for user and system time resp. */
```

Answer (score 0):

Back in the day I used to use pureCoverage to examine the execution time, but it was expensive.  There might be free tools that do the same sort of thing, but for a quick and dirty solution...

```
include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  time_t start_time, end_time;
  start_time = time(NULL);
  //Do your thing...
  end_time  = time(NULL);

  int diff = end_time - start_time;
  //Diff will be the number of milliseconds that elapsed.
}
```

Comment: but how do I tell what is real  user and sys?

Answer (score 0):

There's another solution, not much different from the previous example.

```
#include<time.h>
int main ()
{
    clock_t start_time, stop_time;

    start_time = clock();

    // ... do your thing;

    stop_time = clock();

    printf("Elapsed time: %lf", (double)( stop_time - start_time ) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
}
```